# I'm getting the system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar' error message

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I've been getting this error message on my code

> system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'
>
> Must declare scalar variable @Flag

Here is the code I have so far:

```
try
{
    if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        dbConn.Open();
    }

    dbCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Shop(ShopID,ShopName,Location,Size,CostPerMeter,[TenantID(FK)],Flag)" +
                    "VALUES(@ShopID,@ShopName,@Location,@Size,@CostPerMeter,@[TenantID(FK)],@Flag);", dbConn);

    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShopID", txtPrimary.Text);
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShopName", txtShopName.Text);
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", txtLoc.Text);
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", txtSize.Text);
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostPerMeter", txtCPM.Text);
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[TenantID(FK)]", txtTenID.Text);

    dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    ds.Tables["Shop"].Rows.Add(new object[] { txtPrimary.Text, txtShopName.Text, txtLoc.Text, txtSize.Text, txtCPM.Text, txtTenID.Text, });

    txtPrimary.Clear();
    txtShopName.Clear();
    txtLoc.Clear();
    txtSize.Clear();
    txtCPM.Clear();
    txtTenID.Clear();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You refer to `@Flag` in your query, but never give it a corresponding parameter value. Simply add a parameter value for `@Flag`:

```
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", true); // set however appropriate
```